# Tomcat servlet synchronization

Tags: session, tomcat, servlets, synchronization

Why when I debug my application in tomcat and i invoke 2 request from the same client (same session), the second request is processed only when the first has finished ??? Tomcat sync the servlets of the same session??? This does not happen in jetty

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat does not synchronize servlets.  If there is any synchronization, chances are you've introduced it some how. Perhaps your connecting to a database and haven't configured your connection pool correctly?

Sorry, I just reread your question. You wouldn't have stuck a break point in your code would you? If you did the debugger is going to serialize the execution by stoping at the break point each time a thread hits it. Does that make sense?

Comment: Hi karthik, the first request stop in my breakpoint and the second stop only when the first finish (when a press F8 in eclipse)

Comment: The strange thing is that in jetty not happen